# How to make Javascript function call happen after pauses

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am building a simple game in using HTML5 Canvas/Javascript. However, the game will be passed Javascript functions (js injected into the browser). The code passed will be to move the character ie. "moveRight(); moveRight(); moveUp();".
Currently, i have the character moving, however for "moveRight(); moveRight();", the character teleports itself to its new position. I would like the character to moveRight and then take a pause before moving right again.

[image: The game screen]

```
function right(){
   window.setTimeout(function() {
      character.x += 30;
   }, 2000); 
}
```

How can I accomplish something like this. I tried using a timeout, but it did not help me much.

Thanks,

Comment: can you be more specific and clarify 'but it did not help me much' ? do you maybe want to use setInterval() and continue to execute or just once per right() function call?

Comment: When i inject "right();right();", it waits for 2 seconds and then executes the function twice, without any pause between the calls. I would like to add a delay between the 2 calls automatically.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "animation". You want to play an animation that lasts for a certain duration and then after the animation is over, then the player can choose to move right again?

Comment: @smac89, yes that would work, but ideally id like to just add a pause, so the users can see how each injected line of code has helped move the character. For example, if i inject "right();left();", id like the character to move right, stop for a second and then move left again.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to approach this would be to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), and use a counter for when the player is able to move.

setInterval won't work for this situation, since you need to acknowledge cases where the player moves the other way around, or when the player *cancels* the movement.

It's hard to understand your current logic without more code, but below you will find an approach to a grid based movement.

```js
const c = document.getElementById('canvas');
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');

// player delay for movement
const playerMovementDelay = 2;
const tileSize = 32;
// player starting position
const myPlayer = {x: 1, y: 1, h: 1, w: 1};
let pkl = 0, pkr = 0, pku = 0, pkd = 0;
let pvelx = 0, pvely = 0;
let movementCountdown = 0;

function render() {

  // player logic
  movementCountdown -= 0.16;
  const deltax = pkr + pkl;
  const deltay = pkd + pku;
  if (movementCountdown <= 0 && (deltax != 0 || deltay != 0)) {
    movementCountdown = playerMovementDelay;
    pvelx = deltax;
    pvely = deltay;
  }
  const speed = 1;
  myPlayer.x += pvelx * speed;
  myPlayer.y -= pvely * speed;
  pvelx = pvely = 0;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  // player render
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFD9B3';
  ctx.fillRect(myPlayer.x * tileSize, myPlayer.y * tileSize, myPlayer.w * tileSize, myPlayer.h * tileSize);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') {
    pkr = 1;
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
    pkl = -1;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  
  if (e.key == 'ArrowUp') {
    pku = 1;
    e.preventDefault();
  } else if (e.key == 'ArrowDown') {
    pkd = -1;
    e.preventDefault();
  }

});

window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if (e.key == 'ArrowRight') {
    pkr = 0;
  } else if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft') {
    pkl = 0;
  }
  
  if (e.key == 'ArrowUp') {
    pku = 0;
  } else if (e.key == 'ArrowDown') {
    pkd = 0;
  }
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: The difference is that instead of using keyboard input to change the position, I want to use functions that i can call from the console.

Comment: What do the functions do?

Comment: Well, i have an android Application, that generates js code as a string. I inject the code into a webview running the game, to show how the character moves. The functions are for moving the character in 2d space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval for the same.

```
var rightCount = 1;
var moveRight = function () {
    rightCount++;
    character.x += 30;
}

var move = function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        if (rightCount < 2) {
            moveRight();
        }
    }, 2000)
}

move();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish. The issue is that the character just teleports to the final position. If i call moveRight(); moveRight();, then id like the character to move one spot, and then the second with a pause in between.

Comment: how do i set rightCount back to one, after each function call;

Comment: Do not increment the rightCount. I did so to demonstrate the number of times you want to move. You can even pass a value in the caller for the number of times to move.

Comment: basically i want one moveRight() call to move it right just once. However, when i inject a string of two moveRight() functions, i want it to execute the two and have a pause in between. Sorry if i am unclear.

Comment: When you call moveRight() twice together, there is no way for the second call to know that the call was made earlier, and hence to wait, and to ensure that the second call happens only after the first call has returned.